# building a python function from an arbitrarily long list of parameters

Tags: python

I am trying to construct a python lambda function from either a single parameter or a list, and am unsure what syntax to use to build the lambda:

```
def check_classes_filter(*class):
    return lambda x: isinstance(x, class) and isinstance(x, class[1]...)
```

The lambda should check if x is an instance of any number of classes that is passed to the function (either one or many).

Is there a general way to build functions from an arbitrary number of parameters in python, maybe as a kind of comprehension?

Comment: Why do you want to make a lambda function for this as opposed to an actual function that can handle an arbitrarily long list of objects?

Comment: Well, it's really part of a bigger function that needs to pass a lambda function as a parameter into another function, and I didn't want to change the source code of the function that accepts the lambda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop over your `classes` args using `all`.

```
def check_classes_filter(*classes):
    return lambda x: all(isinstance(x, c) for c in classes)

>>> fun = check_classes_filter(str)
>>> fun('hello')
True
>>> fun = check_classes_filter(int, str)
>>> fun('hello')
False
```

Although I'd prefer just passing in a `list` of classes

```
def check_classes_filter(classes):
    return lambda x: all(isinstance(x, c) for c in classes)
```

and calling the function as

```
check_classes_filter([int, str])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check that an object is an instance of any listed class, you don't need to define anything:

```
>>> isinstance('test', int)
False
>>> isinstance('test', str)
True
>>> isinstance('test', (int, str))
True
```

From [`isinstance` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) :

> If classinfo is a tuple of type objects (or recursively, other such
>   tuples), return true if object is an instance of any of the types.

In your question, you mention `if x is an instance of any number of classes that is passed to the function (either one or many)`, it would mean that you should `or` instead of `and` in your boolean logic. If you want to check that an object is an instance of every listed classes, see the [answer with `all`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45487502/6419007).

Comment: I wanted to use `and` instead of `or`, otherwise I would have just used the built in functionality. Thanks for your response though, I should have made it more clear.